# UTC datetime conversion from string/tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix, time

I have a datetime object , when I simply print it , it returns the follwoing

```
Thu Apr 26 22:51:49 PDT 2018
```

and its returns as a tuple when I do     `print (parsedate_tz(tt))`

```
(2018, 4, 26, 22, 51, 49, 0, 1, -1, -25200)
```

What I am struggling is how to convert this into a datetime object so that I can apply time methods to add or subtract time 
I have tried doing the following but it fails and complains about the format

```
tt= (results[0].create_date)
datetime.strptime(tt , '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

I have tried it with `%Z` as well

I am trying to convert it into `2018-04-26T22:51:49Z` eventually

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the 9-tuple to datetime.datetime as follows (ignoring index 6-8 of it):

```
import datetime
#t = parsedate_tz(tt)
t = (2018, 4, 26, 22, 51, 49, 0, 1, -1, -25200)
tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=t[-1]))
dt = datetime.datetime(*t[0:6], tzinfo=tz)
print(dt)
# ==> 2018-04-26 22:51:49-07:00
```

To convert it to UTC and print it:

```
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(dt_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
# ==> 2018-04-27T05:51:49Z
```

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timezone'
By any chance I can get it into this format ?
2018-04-26T22:51:49Z

Comment: I assumed datetime module is imported.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime, date, time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
from email.utils import parsedate_tz`